Single quote command failed in org-cdlatex
I try to use org mode in Doom Emacs to take math notes. However, I find the single quote command sometimes doesn't work while using org-cdlatex. Whenever I try to use single quote command, emacs autocomplete it with '' , that's two single quotes.
The single quote command works well in the \begin{}\end{} environment.
By the way, after a few searches, at first I think it is because of the conflict between company-mode and cdlatex. But I later find out I might not install the package, since in the package list it shows available not installed.

perhaps it’s because of electric-pair-mode

you can type C-q ' to prevent autocompletion

Thanks, I think I didn't read the manual careful! It just because ' only works inside the latex fragment.
